How to create a generic XPath to message all members in a Facebook group?
I'm working on a Facebook automation script using Selenium to send messages to members of a Facebook group. My script successfully logs into Facebook and navigates to the members section. However, I'm running into an issue where the script can't consistently find or interact with the "Message" button for each member because the XPath seems to vary depending on the member profile.
Here is a portion of the code that attempts to identify members and send them a message:
def send_messages_to_members(driver, message_template, amount_of_leads, delay_between_messages):
    try:
        navigate_to_group(driver)

        action = ActionChains(driver)

        # Scroll to load all members
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(2)

        member_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@href, '/profile.php?id=') or contains(@href, '/people/')]")
        member_elements = member_elements[:amount_of_leads]

        for index, member in enumerate(member_elements):
            try:
                # Hover over member's name to trigger the popup
                action.move_to_element(member).perform()
                time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the popup to appear

                # Avoid messaging Admins, Moderators, or yourself
                if 'Admins & Moderators' in member.text or 'Your Name' in member.text:
                    print("Skipping {}".format(member.text))
                    continue

                try:
                    # Generic XPath for the message button in the popup
                    message_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Message')]")
                    message_button.click()
                    time.sleep(5)  # Wait for the message interface to load

                    try:
                        # Find the message box and send the message
                        message_box = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role='textbox']")
                        message_box.click()
                        message_box.send_keys(message_template)
                        message_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
                        time.sleep(delay_between_messages)  # Wait before moving to the next user
                        print("Message sent successfully to user {}.".format(index + 1))
                    except Exception as e:
                        print("Failed to send message to user {}: {}".format(index + 1, e))
                        continue

                    # Close the message interface
                    close_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Close')]")
                    close_button.click()
                    time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the interface to close

                except Exception as e:
                    print("Failed to click on the message button for user {}: {}".format(index + 1, e))
                    continue

                # Scroll down the member list
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", member)
                time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the scrolling action

            except Exception as e:
                print("Error during message sending: {}".format(e))
                continue

        return "Successfully sent messages to {} users.".format(len(member_elements))
    except Exception as e:
        return "Failed: {}".format(e)

The script sometimes fails to locate the message button using the current XPath:
message_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Message')]")
This seems to be because the structure of the member elements can vary slightly depending on the user. Is there a more generic XPath I can use to reliably find and click the "Message" button for any member? Or are there alternative approaches to ensure the script can always find the correct button?Any advice or insights would be appreciated!

if you do get this working, chances are good that Facebook will temporarily suspend your account thinking you've been hacked.  (at least that happened to me after posting to about 6 or 7 friend's timelines.... it wasn't all that difficult to get my account un-suspended after that, but I'm thinking you'll run up against the same thing so beware...)
